# php order by created_at, midnight always comes first

Tags: php, laravel, sql-order-by

I have a problem with sorting values on my table. I sorted these items by created_at column. Its all good but when the table receives an item on 12:01am to 12:59am, they always appear first in the lists. Im am using custom date format.

```
 $date_time = @date('F j Y g:i a', strtotime(@date('F j Y g:i a')));
```

and has an output of "**April 15 2018 2:07 am**"

my **created_at** column is varchar and the reason for that is I'm using date_default_timezone_set(); because the web server store item in different timezone and ruins the datetime when the item was actually created, that is why i dont use timestamp.

one more thing is that i want these time rendered as posted *3 hours ago* or *yesterday* whatever the case maybe.

Im using laravel 5.6 for this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the date time formatting while rendering you can create a mutator in your model as:

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    return Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('F j Y g:i a', $value)->diffForHumans();
}
```

For sorting, what are you trying to achieve? If you are sorting the dates then I midnight comes first.

Comment: exactly, the midnight comes on top of the list. lets say, first item inserted in the db = April 15, 2018 12:03:23 am and the second item comes at April 15, 2018 1:02:02 am. when I sort it by created_at the second item should be on top of the list because it was the latest. but that is not happening. 

I've change my plan, I did datetime type in the database for created_at column. Im doing {{ $post->created_at)->diffForHumans() }} but i get an error Call to a member function diffForHumans()on string

Comment: add this in your model.
`protected $dates = ['created_at'];`
So that it will return the carbon object